# How to use put and get data from elasticache redis of AWS with golang

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-elasticache

I tried to connect to elasticache to put data but I have not found a method to perform put the data.
How can I put and get data on elasticache resdis of aws?
my code

```
mySession := getAWSSession()
svc := elasticache.New(mySession)

input := &elasticache.CreateCacheClusterInput{
    AutoMinorVersionUpgrade: aws.Bool(true),
    CacheClusterId:          aws.String("my-redis"),
    CacheNodeType:           aws.String("cache.r3.larage"),
    CacheSubnetGroupName:    aws.String("default"),
    Engine:                  aws.String("redis"),
    EngineVersion:           aws.String("3.2.4"),
    NumCacheNodes:           aws.Int64(1),
    Port:                    aws.Int64(6379),
    PreferredAvailabilityZone: aws.String("us-east-1c"),
    SnapshotRetentionLimit:    aws.Int64(7),

}

result, err := svc.CreateCacheCluster(input)
var data = Logo{}
data.name = "test1"
data.logo = "test2"
// how to put and get data from elasticache
```

Answer (score 19):

[This](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/elasticache/) Go SDK that you are using provides APIs for managing your ElastiCache infrastructure, such as create/delete clusters or snapshots, add tags, purchase cache nodes etc. It doesn't provide APIs to put or get items *inside* the cache.

The Redis cluster that ElastiCache gives you is similar to the one that you might have installed on your own. So, you can connect it with the usual Go libraries outside AWS SDK. For e.g., [go-redis/redis](https://github.com/go-redis/redis) or [garyburd/redigo](https://github.com/garyburd/redigo).

In short, use the AWS SDK to manage your ElastiCache infrastructure and Redis' Go clients to put or get items from the cache.

Comment: I think it would be insanely helpful if you could show a short snippet about how exactly to create a Redis client connected to an Elasticache instance